# not able to make div follow when I am scrolling using position as fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have my page divided into two sections - left and right. I have used div to make left navigation and right. In the right navigation I have multiple divs as well. Now when I am scrolling page down, only right portion of page is getting scrolled and left navigation stays right there.

So when I am scrolling page down, I want everything to get scrolled including left and right divs both.

Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g2ahx6nq/

So if you scroll page down, it will only scroll right side not left side. I want to scroll everything down when we are scrolling down including left and right both.

Here is my CSS for left bar div where I am using position as fixed as well but still doesn't work:

```
#leftBar 
{

  background-color: rgb(65, 64, 66);
  box-shadow: 2.996px 0.157px 7.65px 1.35px rgba(40, 40, 41, 0.25); 
  border-right: solid #EF7440;
  border-right-width: 4px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 161px;
}
```

You can ignore missing image and alignment for now. As of now I am trying to fix this scroll down issue.

Comment: That's because you have `position : fixed`.

Comment: I dont understand why you are using `position:fixed`

Comment: Look at [flex-box](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/full/adLPwv/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position fixed is used for items that don't move even when they are scrolled.  I would recommend using absolute instead of fixed.  Absolute positing will keep it in the same spot except for when the page is scrolled.